# How to display external website as part of the app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Referring to the image below, I need to display an external website on the right side of the screen when the link 'All chats' is clicked.

[image],

I tried to use `window.location` to achieve it but this is redirecting my site to the new site.

```
<RouteAuthenticated path={match.path} component={() => { window.location = 'https://www.google.com/'; return null; }} />
```

How can I get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use iframes in the same way you can in standard HTML. Note that most website block being displayed in an iframe in other websites due to XSS vulnerabilities.

```
<iframe id="iFrameExample"
    title="iFrame Example"
    src="https://example.com">
</iframe>
```

One way around this is to use the sandbox attribute for iframes. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for the different sandbox properties but they often will break functionality of the site. Other issues you may run into are iframe breakers which are basically unavoidable unless you have access to the code of the 3rd party website.

Comment: thank you, it was what I was looking for. Didn't realize we can use standard HTML to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, via **iFrames** it is possible to load webpages inside of other web pages.Window.location will not help you to do this. You have to use **iFrames**.

Comment: Thank you, i would've appreciated an example.